# Divide the list in chunks (sub-lists) based on filter criterion

Tags: python, list, tuples, splice

I have a list like this

```
a = ['31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72', '00', '00', '00', '82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e', '00', '00', '00', '00','00', '84', '92', '4d','91']
```

I want to split them into list of tuples and remove the chunk of zeros.

```
li_tup = [('31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72'), ('82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e'), ('84', '92', '4d','91')]
```

When I use the `splice[index:index]` the original list remains the same. So the loop iterates over the same item. How do I remove the spliced items from the original list? So I dont have to iterate over it again.

Comment: I don't see the code you're using to split them, but you'll probably just want to use `del splice[index:index]` after you pull it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension answer that doesn't require importing `itertools`:

```
>>> a = ['31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72', '00', '00', '00', '82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e', '00', '00', '00', '00','00', '84', '92', '4d','91']
>>> [ tuple(b.strip().split()) for b in ' '.join(a).split('00 ') if b ]
[('31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72'), ('82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e'), ('84', '92', '4d', '91')]
```

Comparison with other other approaches (for 10,000 iterations):

- This approach using *joining and splitting* takes - 0.214s
- [*MosesKoledoye*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40271222/2063361) using *`itertools.groupby()` with for loop* takes - 0.372s,
- [*anonymous*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40271322/2063361) using *`itertools.groupby()` with list comprehension* takes - 0.321s

(not including the time it takes for their codes to import `itertools`)

Comment: You are right about the execution time part. This is faster. `itertools.groupsby()` approach is slower due to the usage of `lambda` within the expression.

Answer (score 6):

*List Comprehension* expression using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = ['31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72', '00', '00', '00', '82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e', '00', '00', '00', '00','00', '84', '92', '4d','91']

>>> [tuple(group) for is_valid, group in groupby(a, lambda x: x!='00') if is_valid]
[('31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72'), ('82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e'), ('84', '92', '4d', '91')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) since we don't have the indices of the items that are `'00'` beforehand:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = ['31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72', '00', '00', '00', '82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e', '00', '00', '00', '00','00', '84', '92', '4d','91']

result = []
for i, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x!='00'):
    if i:
        result.append(tuple(g))
print(result)
# [('31', '20', '54', '68', '65', '72'), ('82', '4d', '61', '72', '67', '69', '6e'), ('84', '92', '4d', '91')]
```